# Unable to include Vue module in PHP/HTML page: SyntaxError: import not found: VueNativeSock

Tags: php, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, yii2

I'm building an hybrid app: it's a static Yii2 (php) webapp with some portions of Vue.js.

I'm successfully using Vue via [antkaz/yii2-vue](https://github.com/antkaz/yii2-vue), but now I'm unable to include [vue-native-websocket](https://github.com/nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket) Vue module in the page.

(After long troubleshooting and with the help of [Matt LaGrandeur's tips](https://medium.com/@mattlag/es6-modules-getting-started-gotchas-2ad154f38e2e))I've added this html block to the page:

```html
<script type="module">
    import { VueNativeSock } from '/web/assets/a95a22eb/dist/build.js'
    Vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'ws://localhost:9090')
</script>
```

But I still get this error in FF65:

> SyntaxError: import not found: VueNativeSock

And I'm stuck! If I remove the curly brackets (before the above tips) I get

> SyntaxError: import not found: default

How can I import the module? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the assets folder is that the folder name could change.  When you register the Vue asset you can save the instance of the registered asset.  If you `var_dump()` this is there a path there that you can save?

```
vueAsset = VueAsset::register($this); 
var_dump( $vueAsset );
```

Comment: in fact shouldn't your import be just '/assets/a95a22eb/dist/build.js' - I still wouldn't rely on using the assets folder hard coded though.

Comment: I didn't hardcode the asset path, it was just an example. Once published, using the `register` function and obtained the path, the above was the generated html. Once that has been done, I still got *import not found*

Comment: So do you need the "/web"?

Comment: no, I don't have 404 error! It must be something in the module itself